# preg_replace youtube links - iframe embed

Tags: php, youtube, preg-replace, hyperlink

I am trying to replace youtube links including the a tags with the iframe embed code.
What I got so far:

```
$tube_link = "<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XA5Qf8VHh9I&amp;feature=g-all-u&amp;context=G2f50f6aFAAAAAAAADAA" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XA5Qf8VHh9I&amp;feature=g-all-u&amp;context=G2f50f6aFAAAAAAAADAA</a>"

$search = '%<a(.*)(?:href="https?://)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be/|youtube\.com(?:/embed/|/v/|/watch\?v= ))([\w\-]{10,12})(?:)([\w\-]{0})\b%x';

$replace = '<iframe width="150" height="84" src="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/$2"></iframe>';

$embed_code = preg_replace($search, $replace, $tube_link);
```

Result:

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/XA5Qf8VHh9"></iframe>&amp;feature=g-all-u&amp;context=G2f50f6aFAAAAAAAADAA</a>
```

How can I get rid of the remaining:

```
&amp;feature=g-all-u&amp;context=G2f50f6aFAAAAAAAADAA</a>
```

Thnx!

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML. It's ill suited for the task. Use XPath or something similar instead. It will work a lot better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
$search =
 '#<a(.*?)(?:href="https?://)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be/|youtube\.com(?:/embed/|/v/|/watch\?v=))([\w\-]{10,12}).*$#x';
```

**TESTING:**

```
$tube_link = '<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XA5Qf8VHh9I&amp;feature=g-all-u&amp;context=G2f50f6aFAAAAAAAADAA" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XA5Qf8VHh9I&amp;feature=g-all-u&amp;context=G2f50f6aFAAAAAAAADAA</a>';
$search = '#<a(.*?)(?:href="https?://)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be/|youtube\.com(?:/embed/|/v/|/watch\?v=))([\w\-]{10,12}).*$#x';
$replace = '<iframe width="150" height="84" src="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/$2"></iframe>';
$embed_code = preg_replace($search, $replace, $tube_link);
var_dump($embed_code);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
string(97) "<iframe width="150" height="84" src="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/XA5Qf8VHh9I"></iframe>"
```

Comment: Thnx, just what I was looking for.

Comment: how would you do this for youtube links that have hashes at the end for timing?

E.g: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jECIv7zlD4c&feature=player_embedded#t=30s"

Comment: @Luc This is very old question, pls post a new one and then I will try to find a suitable answer for you.

Comment: thanks @anubhava Please find my post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15147993/youtube-embedded-video-pregreplace-with-start-timing

Answer (score 0):

if you're sure that YouTube link is valid you can just use simple form

```
$search = '/^.*?v=(\w*?)&.*$/';
```

with replacement **`$1`**.

[See example here!](http://www.rubular.com/r/3Z5HHIMpK6)

Or add `.*$` at the end of your pattern to mark everything until the end of subject string.

Comment: Thnx for your reply. Not exactly what I was looking for, but useful none the less.